# Run shell script in pod remotely openshift or kubernetes

Tags: shell, kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-pod

I have one shell script I want to run that remotely in POD, how I can do that?

```
 oc exec build-core-1-p4fr4 -- df -kh /   <---  I want to use my script
```

any way to do this remotely, like we do

```
oc exec build-core-1-p4fr4 -- cat >> text << shell.sh <---- something like this
```

I checked `oc rsh` but didn't find anything specific there.

Answer (score 4):

You can try the following command using `-i` option that allows to pass stdin to the container.

```
$ oc exec -i your_pod_name -- /bin/bash -s <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
date > /tmp/time
EOF

$ oc exec your_pod_name -- cat /tmp/time
Fri Nov 13 10:00:19 UTC 2020
$
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `oc exec -i` to take script from stdin.

```sh
oc exec -i your_pod_name -- bash -s < your_script.sh
```